# Send shrink Command to Microsoft SQL Database file via Ado.net connection

Tags: sql, ado.net

How is it possible to execute a direct SQL command to an ADO.NET connected database? 
I want to send a `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` to the SQL server, to compress the current datafile after a big deletion process. The function `ObjectContext::CreateQuery` returns a parser error after the DBCC command. Is there any other way to shrink the database file, or another way to send the SQL command directly to the SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just send this as raw SQL:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(0)", connection))
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Another way is to put the `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure from your code.

Comment: sending raw SQL would be ok, but how can raw SQL be send over the ADO.Net connection without parsing the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

thanks Mark, I just had to figure out how I can obtain the  SqlConnection.
Here is the complete sourcecode (ok could be written a little bit nicer with an extension method):

```
    public ActionResult Optimize()
    {
        using (BXPartsEntities Entities = new BXPartsEntities())
        {

            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection eConnection = Entities.Connection as System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection;

            eConnection.Open();

            var SqlConnection = eConnection.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;

            if (SqlConnection == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("StoreConnection shall be SQL Connection");

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(0)", SqlConnection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            eConnection.Close();
        }
        return Content("Done");
    }
```